The copy line down keyboard shortcut is not working in Visual Studio Code
Recently when I was coding in HTML in Visual Studio Code, the 'copy line down' shortcut stopped working and instead of copying the text down it is selecting the lines below.
In the keyboard shortcuts, the shortcut for copying line down is 'alt+shift+down arrow key' but somehow it is not working. What should I do?

Run the Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Trubleshooting command and report those results.  In the Keyboard Shortcuts, is there any other command displayed with the same shortcut?
